# I am getting an error with (..).each do |x| .. end in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error for the below part of code:

```
element = driver.find_element :name => "used_by"
element.send_keys "371101"
element = driver.find_element :name => "btnSearch"
element.click
all_table_data = driver.find_element(:tag_name, "td").text

all_table_data.each do |td|
   puts td.text
end
print element
```

Error:

```
D:\Ruby script>ruby filedownload.rb
filedownload.rb:24:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for #<Selenium::WebDrive
r::Element:0x2556be8> (NoMethodError)

D:\Ruby script>
```

can anyone help me to fix the error?

Comment: Can any one look into the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element` only returns the **first** element matching the given arguments.

What you probably what is the [`find_elements` method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_elements-instance_method) which finds all elements matching the given arguments:

```
all_table_data = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "td")

all_table_data.each do |td|
   puts td.text
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the modified code? Because you cannot get the same error message... Which version of the WebDriver are you using?

Comment: I just accepted, your answer. It was previously throwing an error, not running perfectly! :) I used [doc](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) . you referred another one. So could you advice me which one is best?

Comment: Your link is pointing the official documentation which is also fine if you want to learn how to use WebDriver. What I've linked is the API documentation which contains all the documentation of the Selenium::WebDriver generated directly from source which is usefull if you want to find out how the WebDriver works internally in more details.